# Find $f$ that is integrability in $[0,2]$ so that $F(x) =\int f(t)dt$ is not differentiate $[0,2]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

I need to find a function that is integrability in $[0,2]$ so that $F(x)=\int f(t)dt$ is not differentiate $[0,2]$.

Please avoid any "famous" functions (Weierstrass, etc..), because I'm not able to use in my exam, I'm looking for something "simple".

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,{\rm d}t$. The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $f$ is continuous, then $F$ is differentiable and $F' = f$. So we must take $f$ discontinuous. Try $f:[0,2]\to \Bbb R$ given by: $$f(t) = \begin{cases} 1,& \text{if } t \in [0,1] \\ 2,& \text{if } t \in ]0,2]\end{cases}.$$
Write explicitly the definition of $F$, it will have two parts, like $f$ above. Then $F'(1)$ won't exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in this case $F'(1)$ won't exists I'm not sure its fulfill the question since its not differentiable in one point and the question request that the function is not differentiable in $[0,2]$.

Comment: The statement "$F$ is differentiable in $[0,2]$" means that $F'(x)$ exists, for all $x \in [0,2]$. The denial of this statement is that exists at least one value of $x$ in $[0,2]$ such that $F'(x)$ does not exists. This is merely logic. Now, if you want that $F$ isn't differentiable in *any* point, you must take $f$ discontinuous everywhere, and so we must take difficult examples such as Weierstrass' function, etc (which you do not want now)

Comment: A Riemann integrable function is continuous almost everywhere, so $F$ will be differentiable almost everywhere. It is not possible to find an example where $F$ is not differentiable anywhere.

Comment: "An integrable function is continuous almost everywhere" is true only when talking about Riemann-integrability, no? The function $\chi_{\Bbb Q}$ in $[0,1]$ is everywhere discontinuous, but is Lebesgue-integrable.

Comment: Fair enough, but do we really think the OP is talking about Lebesgue integrability here?

Comment: Also note that, using the Lebesgue integral, for the characteristic function of the rationals the function $F$ is the constant zero function, which is differentiable.

Comment: I was thinking that the notion of "primitive" was independent of the integral we're working with. If this is not the case, then you've made your point `:)`